# Yii Bootstrap Extension Gridview

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I have been using CGridView without any issues previously but when I use Bootstrap extension the filters stop working.

Moreover the Ajax requests for CButtonColumn are set to use POST but when I use BootButtonColumn it uses GET and ignores the fact that ajax type is set to POST

Any ideas on how to fix the problems.

Answer (score 0):

I went back to using zii widgets but today looking at the documentation for a totally unrelated reason I came across this property "ajaxUpdate". Below is the excerpt from Yii documentation.

ajaxUpdate property

`public mixed $ajaxUpdate;`

the ID of the container whose content may be updated with an AJAX response. Defaults to null, meaning the container for this grid view instance. If it is set false, it means sorting and pagination will be performed in normal page requests instead of AJAX requests. If the sorting and pagination should trigger the update of multiple containers' content in AJAX fashion, these container IDs may be listed here (separated with comma).

I am no longer using that extension but I am posting it here so that it maybe helpful to someone else.